# Microsoft Active Accessibility in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, accessibility

Does anyone have any pointers on where to start with this?

I'm using MS UI Automation to do some acceptance testing of an application, but the MenuStrip control doesn't support MSUIA, and apparently the only way to get what I want from it is Active Accessibility (MSAA).

Sadly, there appears to be very little available on how to act as a MSAA client in C#.

If anyone has any pointers I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you have to use COM interop to write a MSAA client in C#.